# Sort Matlab data into groups

Tags: matlab

I have a column of numerical data (imported from excel) and I would like to sort each of the column entries into 4 different groups based on custom size ranges, then calculate how many column entries are in each group, as a fraction of the total number of entries in the column.

For example, if my column was 1,3,13,11,5,9. I want to calculate how many entries fit into group 1-3, how many fit into group 4-7, and so on. Then calculate the amount of entries in each group as a fraction of the total number of column entries. ie, 6 in this example.

Does anyone know how to do this best?

Thanks

Hannah :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Sry I misread your question:
here is the updated code

```
ranges = [1 3
          4 7
          8 11
          12 13];

groups = size(ranges,1);

a = [ 1,3,13,11,5,9];

counter = zeros(groups,1);
for i=1:groups
    counter(i) = sum(a>=ranges(i,1) & a<=ranges(i,2));
end
relative_counter = counter / numel(a);
```

**Old answer:**

I do not understand how you get your group bounds (in your question the first group has 3 elements and the 2nd group has 4?)

have a look at the following code. (be careful and test how it should behave at group boarders)

```
groups =4;
a = [ 1,3,13,11,5,9];
range = max(a)-min(a);
rangePerGroup = range/groups;

a_noOffset = a-min(a);

counter = zeros(groups,1);
for i=1:groups
    counter(i) = sum(a_noOffset>=rangePerGroup*(i-1) & a_noOffset<=rangePerGroup*i);
end
relative_counter = counter / numel(a);
```